# Oracle SQL: select from table with nested table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, nested-table

I wonder how can i make select statement from table which have a typed column ?
Type of this column is defined as:

```
create or replace TYPE "MYCOL" as table of MYTYPE; 
create or replace TYPE "MYTYPE" as OBJECT
( myid Number, myname Varchar2);
```

**UPD1**
Table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE "T_TABLE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, "NAME" "MYCOL" )
```

If i select this column with `select * from T_TABLE`  i will get this not informative result:

```
1, MYSCHEMA.MYCOL([MYSCHEMA.MYTYPE],[MYSCHEMA.MYTYPE])
```

I want just to unwrap this types.

Comment: and how is your table defined?

Comment: The display is handled by the SQL client. SQL*Plus will display this as e.g.: `MYCOL(MYTYPE(1, 'somevalue'))`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
select t."ID", tt.myid, tt.myname 
from "T_TABLE" t, table(t."NAME") tt;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d847/1)

Comment: How do you return rows from this query if there is no rows in the nested table?